# How to prevent slideToggle opening then closing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have a `slideToggle` which is giving me an accordion-style function. This all works fine except for the first click which shows the content div briefly but then slides it closed straight away. Clicking again slides open correctly and all subsequent clicks function correctly.

Here's the Jquery script I'm using:

```
$(".tm-section-label").click(function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('.tm-extra-product-options-container').slideToggle('fast,easing'); 
       });~
    $(".tm-section-label").click(function() {
 $(".tm-section-label").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.tm-extra-product-options-container').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Here's the CSS I'm using :

```
.prodTabs div.cpf_hide_element {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.prodTabs.active > div.tm-extra-product-options-container {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

.prodTabs.active div.cpf_hide_element {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I make the initial click just slide the div open without having to click twice?

Comment: can you share html code also

Comment: Looks OK, must be something subtle.

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hpJDeF

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .prodTabs div.cpf_hide_element {
            display: none;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .prodTabs.active > div.tm-extra-product-options-container {
            visibility: visible;
            height: auto;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .prodTabs.active div.cpf_hide_element {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Script to illustrates slideToggle() method -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tm-section-label").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                var q = $(this).parent().find('.tm-extra-product-options-container');
                if (q.hasClass('cpf_hide_element')) {

                    q.removeClass('cpf_hide_element');
                }
                else {
                    q.slideToggle('fast,easing');
                    q.removeClass('cpf_hide_element');
                }
            });
            $(".tm-section-label").click(function () {
                $(".tm-section-label").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.tm-extra-product-options-container').slideUp('fast');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="prodTabs" id="parent">
        <div class="tm-extra-product-options-container cpf_hide_element" id="theContent">The content..</div>
        <div class="tm-section-label">Click Me</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```